# Converting an JSON string to Gson object

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I have an JSONObject which is creating in the following way.
For a special reason, I have to convert it to Gson in this way, as i can modify only extractDataToString() method. But I do not get proper value after conversion.

```
fun createJsonString() {
    val headerJson = JSONObject()
    headerJson.put("typ1", "value1")
    headerJson.put("typ2", "value2")
    extractData(headerJson.toString())
} 

fun extractDataToString(jsonString: String) {
    val headerJson = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject::class.java)
    val resultType1 = headerJson.remove("typ1")?.toString() // Here, resultType1 becomes 
                                                                "value1", but it should be 
                                                                 value1 that is extra qutomation 
                                                                 mark is being added.
}
```

Why extra quotation mark is being added? Can anyone please help? I am a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call

```
.getAsString()
```

Instead of

```
toString()
```

at the end
ref : [docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer)